# Navigating Directories in R Script Scheduled via Cron

Tags: r, cron

I have some web scraping code developed in RSelenium that I'm trying to use to download a series of CSV files and move them into a desired folder. I'm trying to schedule the file to run regularly with cron. The script runs and downloads the files fine, but I can't access the files in my downloaded folder. When I run list.files() I get the following code returned. Here is simple code for an example.

Code:

```
print(getwd())

print("setting the working director to /Users/paulcaih/")
setwd("/Users/paulcaih/") #set the working directory to someplace where you can access downloads and dropbox
print("the current directory is")
print(getwd())

print("the files in the current directory are:")
print(list.files())

print("the files in the downloads folder are:")
print(list.files("Downloads"))
```

Here is the output from RStudio

```
> print("current working directory is:")
[1] "current working directory is:"
> print(getwd())
[1] "/Users/paulcaih"
> print("setting the working director to /Users/paulcaih/")
[1] "setting the working director to /Users/paulcaih/"
> setwd("/Users/paulcaih/") #set the working directory to someplace where you can access downloads and dropbox
> print("the current directory is")
[1] "the current directory is"
> print(getwd())
[1] "/Users/paulcaih"
> print("the files in the current directory are:")
[1] "the files in the current directory are:"
> print(list.files())
 [1] "COVID Testing and MH Domains.txt" "Desktop"                          "Documents"                       
 [4] "Downloads"                        "Dropbox"                          "Google Drive"                    
 [7] "Library"                          "Movies"                           "Music"                           
[10] "OneDrive"                         "OneDrive - Johns Hopkins"         "Pictures"                        
[13] "Public"                           "R"                                "Zotero"                          
> print("the files in the downloads folder are:")
[1] "the files in the downloads folder are:"
> print(list.files("Downloads"))
  [1] "~$i_2020_04_18_green_1_sdc2.docx"                                                        
  [2] "0. BAHI Imputation_Attempts Only (1).R"                                                  
  [3] "0. BAHI Imputation_Attempts Only.R"                                                      
  [4] "0. School Dashboard Cleaning File_10.01.21.do"                                           
  [5] "0. School Dashboard Historical Data Cleaning File_10.08.21.do"                           
  [6] "00000PORTRAIT_00000_BURST20190919103002186.jpg"                                          
  [7] "00126334-202007011-00010.pdf"   
...
```

And here is the output from the log file when job runs as a Cron job.

```
[1] "current working directory is:"
[1] "/Users/paulcaih"
[1] "setting the working director to /Users/paulcaih/"
[1] "the current directory is"
[1] "/Users/paulcaih"
[1] "the files in the current directory are:"
 [1] "COVID Testing and MH Domains.txt" "Desktop"                         
 [3] "Documents"                        "Downloads"                       
 [5] "Dropbox"                          "Google Drive"                    
 [7] "Library"                          "Movies"                          
 [9] "Music"                            "OneDrive"                        
[11] "OneDrive - Johns Hopkins"         "Pictures"                        
[13] "Public"                           "R"                               
[15] "Zotero"                          
[1] "the files in the downloads folder are:"
character(0)
```

I'm running macOS 11.5.2 on a m1 macbook pro. I'm setting my cron job up through cronR with the following code:

```
cmd <- cron_rscript("Dropbox/School Surveillance Project - CAIH/16. Data Analysis/School Testing Brief Report/Cron Directory Example.R")


cron_add(command = cmd, frequency = 'daily', at = "9:41" , id = 'test_download_scheduler', description = "testing concentric download cron job")
```

Comment: The better way to know what directory it is running in is to use `getwd()`, not infer from the existing files. I doubt that helps resolve the issue, but it is more concise and precise. As to where your files are ending up, I think we'll need to see the relevant download code to see where the files are being dropped.

Comment: Thanks, I do check with getwd() earlier in the code, just didn't post it. I'm on macOS, just setting the wd to my username. here's the printout in the cron log. 1] "Current working directory:"
[1] "/Users/paulcaih"

Comment: The files get downloaded to my /Users/paulcaih/Downloads folder. I can access them fine with the script in R studio and can see them using the finder after the cron job finishes running.

Comment: Okay, then if your R script is downloading them to that directory while you are running it in RStudio, then perhaps under cron the script is running in a different directory or is not running correctly. What indication do you have the the script is running without error and downloading relevant data/files?

Comment: I edited the description above to be more clear. Hopefully that helps. With the original code, I can tell it's running because RSelenium actually opens a browser to download the files which I can see. I can also see output up until the point where I'm trying to read in the new files from the downloads folder where I see an error message in the log from the cron file.

Comment: Also of note, this demo script runs fine and is able to get all of the files in the Downloads folder when run manually from terminal.

Comment: I completely understand that the script is running fine when interactive. It seems apparent that your `"Cron Directory Example.R"` script behaves differently between interactive and non-interactive use. I can't help, I don't know what that file is trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, r2evans! Appreciate the effort!